# Get product id from recurring profile Array

Tags: magento

I am Using an Observer on Place Order for Recurring Profile

> public function SubscribePlan($observer){
>
> ```
>           $profileIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
>
>    if ($profileIds && is_array($profileIds)) {
>         $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile')->getCollection()
>             ->addFieldToFilter('profile_id', array('in' => $profileIds))
>         ;
>         $profiles = array();
>         foreach ($collection as $profile) {
>
>   $profiles[]= $profile;
>
>
>
>
>         }
>
>
>           echo"<pre>"; print_r($profiles); echo"</pre>";      die('dead');
> ```
>
> }

and Printing Array , It Give me Array like this

> [profile_id] => 53
>                       [state] => active
>                       [customer_id] => 10
>                       [store_id] => 1
>                       [method_code] => paypal_express
>                       [created_at] => 2014-06-25 06:04:43
>                       [updated_at] => 2014-06-25 06:04:44
>                       [reference_id] => I-KJXWM42XC01K
>                       [subscriber_name] => 
>                       [start_datetime] => 2014-06-25 06:04:44
>                       [internal_reference_id] => 53-4ba91ddd43b6d2d377378a5aba7f3908
>                       [schedule_description] => One Year
>                       [suspension_threshold] => 5
>                       [bill_failed_later] => 0
>                       [period_unit] => year
>                       [period_frequency] => 1
>                       [period_max_cycles] => 
>                       [billing_amount] => 100.0000
>                       [trial_period_unit] => 
>                       [trial_period_frequency] => 
>                       [trial_period_max_cycles] => 
>                       [trial_billing_amount] => 
>                       [currency_code] => USD
>                       [shipping_amount] => 5.0000
>                       [tax_amount] => 
>                       [init_amount] => 
>                       [init_may_fail] => 0
>                      [order_info] => a:56:{s:9:"entity_id";s:2:"72";s:8:"store_id";s:1:"1";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:03:28";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:04:38";s:12:"converted_at";N;s:9:"is_active";s:1:"1";s:10:"is_virtual";s:1:"0";s:17:"is_multi_shipping";s:1:"0";s:11:"items_count";i:1;s:9:"items_qty";d:1;s:13:"orig_order_id";s:1:"0";s:18:"store_to_base_rate";s:6:"1.0000";s:19:"store_to_quote_rate";s:6:"1.0000";s:18:"base_currency_code";s:3:"USD";s:19:"store_currency_code";s:3:"USD";s:19:"quote_currency_code";s:3:"USD";s:11:"grand_total";d:0;s:16:"base_grand_total";d:0;s:15:"checkout_method";N;s:11:"customer_id";s:2:"10";s:21:"customer_tax_class_id";s:1:"3";s:17:"customer_group_id";s:1:"1";s:14:"customer_email";s:17:"krn@ocodewire.com";s:15:"customer_prefix";N;s:18:"customer_firstname";s:5:"Karan";s:19:"customer_middlename";N;s:17:"customer_lastname";s:8:"Adhikari";s:15:"customer_suffix";N;s:12:"customer_dob";N;s:13:"customer_note";N;s:20:"customer_note_notify";s:1:"1";s:17:"customer_is_guest";s:1:"0";s:9:"remote_ip";s:14:"112.196.22.234";s:16:"applied_rule_ids";s:0:"";s:17:"reserved_order_id";s:9:"100000057";s:13:"password_hash";N;s:11:"coupon_code";N;s:20:"global_currency_code";s:3:"USD";s:19:"base_to_global_rate";s:6:"1.0000";s:18:"base_to_quote_rate";s:6:"1.0000";s:15:"customer_taxvat";N;s:15:"customer_gender";s:4:"male";s:8:"subtotal";d:0;s:13:"base_subtotal";d:0;s:22:"subtotal_with_discount";d:0;s:27:"base_subtotal_with_discount";d:0;s:10:"is_changed";s:1:"1";s:17:"trigger_recollect";i:0;s:17:"ext_shipping_info";N;s:15:"gift_message_id";N;s:13:"is_persistent";s:1:"0";s:15:"x_forwarded_for";N;s:17:"virtual_items_qty";i:0;s:15:"taxes_for_items";a:0:{}s:14:"can_apply_msrp";b:0;s:21:"totals_collected_flag";b:1;}
>                       [order_item_info] => a:74:{s:7:"item_id";s:2:"88";s:8:"quote_id";s:2:"72";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:03:28";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:03:28";s:10:"product_id";s:1:"6";s:8:"store_id";s:1:"1";s:14:"parent_item_id";N;s:10:"is_virtual";s:1:"0";s:3:"sku";s:10:"one-yr-sub";s:4:"name";s:8:"One Year";s:11:"description";N;s:16:"applied_rule_ids";s:0:"";s:15:"additional_data";N;s:13:"free_shipping";s:1:"0";s:14:"is_qty_decimal";s:1:"0";s:11:"no_discount";s:1:"0";s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0010";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:5:"price";d:100;s:10:"base_price";d:100;s:12:"custom_price";N;s:16:"discount_percent";i:0;s:15:"discount_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_discount_amount";i:0;s:11:"tax_percent";i:0;s:10:"tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"base_tax_amount";i:0;s:9:"row_total";d:100;s:14:"base_row_total";d:100;s:23:"row_total_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:10:"row_weight";d:0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375;s:12:"product_type";s:6:"simple";s:24:"base_tax_before_discount";N;s:19:"tax_before_discount";N;s:21:"original_custom_price";N;s:12:"redirect_url";N;s:9:"base_cost";N;s:14:"price_incl_tax";d:100;s:19:"base_price_incl_tax";d:100;s:18:"row_total_incl_tax";d:100;s:23:"base_row_total_incl_tax";d:100;s:17:"hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:22:"base_hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"gift_message_id";N;s:20:"weee_tax_disposition";i:0;s:24:"weee_tax_row_disposition";i:0;s:25:"base_weee_tax_disposition";i:0;s:29:"base_weee_tax_row_disposition";i:0;s:16:"weee_tax_applied";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"weee_tax_applied_amount";i:0;s:27:"weee_tax_applied_row_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_weee_tax_applied_amount";i:0;s:30:"base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt";N;s:11:"qty_options";a:0:{}s:12:"tax_class_id";s:1:"0";s:12:"is_recurring";s:1:"1";s:9:"has_error";b:0;s:10:"is_nominal";b:1;s:22:"base_calculation_price";d:100;s:17:"calculation_price";d:100;s:15:"converted_price";d:100;s:19:"base_original_price";d:100;s:14:"taxable_amount";d:100;s:19:"base_taxable_amount";d:100;s:17:"is_price_incl_tax";b:0;s:14:"original_price";d:100;s:32:"base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount";i:0;s:25:"discount_tax_compensation";i:0;s:20:"base_shipping_amount";d:5;s:15:"shipping_amount";d:5;s:17:"nominal_row_total";d:105;s:22:"base_nominal_row_total";d:105;s:21:"nominal_total_details";a:0:{}s:15:"info_buyRequest";s:225:"a:4:{s:4:"uenc";s:124:"aHR0cDovL2J3Y211bHRpbWVkaWEuY29tL0UvZXh0ZW5zaW9udGVzdC9pbmRleC5waHAvbXVsdGl2ZW5kb3IvdmVuZG9ycHJvZHVjdHMvc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLw,,";s:7:"product";s:1:"6";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"be2eDRXu1MC7OXfK";s:3:"qty";i:1;}";}
>                       [billing_address_info] => a:97:{s:10:"address_id";s:3:"145";s:8:"quote_id";s:2:"72";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:03:28";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:04:38";s:11:"customer_id";s:2:"10";s:20:"save_in_address_book";s:1:"0";s:19:"customer_address_id";N;s:12:"address_type";s:7:"billing";s:5:"email";s:23:"sukhwantc@ocodewire.com";s:6:"prefix";N;s:9:"firstname";s:4:"test";s:10:"middlename";N;s:8:"lastname";s:4:"test";s:6:"suffix";N;s:7:"company";s:9:"OcodeTest";s:6:"street";s:9:"1 Main St";s:4:"city";s:8:"San Jose";s:6:"region";s:10:"California";s:9:"region_id";s:2:"12";s:8:"postcode";s:5:"95131";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"US";s:9:"telephone";s:10:"9085656554";s:3:"fax";N;s:15:"same_as_billing";s:1:"1";s:13:"free_shipping";i:0;s:22:"collect_shipping_rates";s:1:"0";s:15:"shipping_method";N;s:20:"shipping_description";N;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";i:0;s:13:"base_subtotal";i:0;s:22:"subtotal_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:27:"base_subtotal_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:10:"tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"base_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"shipping_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_shipping_amount";i:0;s:19:"shipping_tax_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_shipping_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"discount_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_discount_amount";i:0;s:11:"grand_total";d:0;s:16:"base_grand_total";d:0;s:14:"customer_notes";N;s:13:"applied_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:20:"discount_description";N;s:24:"shipping_discount_amount";N;s:29:"base_shipping_discount_amount";N;s:17:"subtotal_incl_tax";i:0;s:28:"base_subtotal_total_incl_tax";N;s:17:"hidden_tax_amount";N;s:22:"base_hidden_tax_amount";N;s:26:"shipping_hidden_tax_amount";N;s:29:"base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt";N;s:17:"shipping_incl_tax";i:0;s:22:"base_shipping_incl_tax";i:0;s:6:"vat_id";N;s:12:"vat_is_valid";N;s:14:"vat_request_id";N;s:16:"vat_request_date";N;s:19:"vat_request_success";N;s:15:"gift_message_id";N;s:24:"should_ignore_validation";b:1;s:16:"extra_tax_amount";i:0;s:21:"base_extra_tax_amount";i:0;s:28:"recurring_initial_fee_amount";i:0;s:33:"base_recurring_initial_fee_amount";i:0;s:16:"cached_items_all";a:0:{}s:20:"cached_items_nominal";a:0:{}s:23:"cached_items_nonnominal";a:0:{}s:30:"recurring_trial_payment_amount";i:0;s:35:"base_recurring_trial_payment_amount";i:0;s:23:"nominal_subtotal_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_nominal_subtotal_amount";i:0;s:9:"total_qty";i:0;s:19:"base_virtual_amount";i:0;s:14:"virtual_amount";i:0;s:22:"base_subtotal_incl_tax";i:0;s:23:"nominal_discount_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_nominal_discount_amount";i:0;s:16:"applied_rule_ids";s:0:"";s:19:"nominal_weee_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_nominal_weee_amount";i:0;s:18:"nominal_tax_amount";i:0;s:23:"base_nominal_tax_amount";i:0;s:11:"msrp_amount";i:0;s:16:"base_msrp_amount";i:0;s:19:"freeshipping_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_freeshipping_amount";i:0;s:11:"weee_amount";i:0;s:16:"base_weee_amount";i:0;s:18:"free_method_weight";i:0;s:19:"tax_shipping_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_tax_shipping_amount";i:0;s:16:"shipping_taxable";i:0;s:21:"base_shipping_taxable";i:0;s:20:"is_shipping_incl_tax";b:0;}
>                       [shipping_address_info] => a:103:{s:10:"address_id";s:3:"146";s:8:"quote_id";s:2:"72";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:03:28";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 06:04:38";s:11:"customer_id";s:2:"10";s:20:"save_in_address_book";s:1:"0";s:19:"customer_address_id";N;s:12:"address_type";s:8:"shipping";s:5:"email";s:23:"sukhwantc@ocodewire.com";s:6:"prefix";N;s:9:"firstname";s:4:"test";s:10:"middlename";N;s:8:"lastname";s:4:"test";s:6:"suffix";N;s:7:"company";s:9:"OcodeTest";s:6:"street";s:9:"1 Main St";s:4:"city";s:8:"San Jose";s:6:"region";s:10:"California";s:9:"region_id";s:2:"12";s:8:"postcode";s:5:"95131";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"US";s:9:"telephone";s:10:"9085656554";s:3:"fax";N;s:15:"same_as_billing";s:1:"0";s:13:"free_shipping";i:0;s:22:"collect_shipping_rates";b:1;s:15:"shipping_method";s:17:"flatrate_flatrate";s:20:"shipping_description";s:17:"Flat Rate - Fixed";s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";i:0;s:13:"base_subtotal";i:0;s:22:"subtotal_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:27:"base_subtotal_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:10:"tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"base_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"shipping_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_shipping_amount";i:0;s:19:"shipping_tax_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_shipping_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"discount_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_discount_amount";i:0;s:11:"grand_total";d:0;s:16:"base_grand_total";d:0;s:14:"customer_notes";N;s:13:"applied_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:20:"discount_description";s:0:"";s:24:"shipping_discount_amount";i:0;s:29:"base_shipping_discount_amount";i:0;s:17:"subtotal_incl_tax";i:0;s:28:"base_subtotal_total_incl_tax";N;s:17:"hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:22:"base_hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:26:"shipping_hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:29:"base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt";N;s:17:"shipping_incl_tax";i:0;s:22:"base_shipping_incl_tax";i:0;s:6:"vat_id";N;s:12:"vat_is_valid";N;s:14:"vat_request_id";N;s:16:"vat_request_date";N;s:19:"vat_request_success";N;s:15:"gift_message_id";N;s:24:"should_ignore_validation";b:1;s:16:"extra_tax_amount";i:0;s:21:"base_extra_tax_amount";i:0;s:28:"recurring_initial_fee_amount";i:0;s:33:"base_recurring_initial_fee_amount";i:0;s:16:"cached_items_all";a:0:{}s:20:"cached_items_nominal";a:0:{}s:23:"cached_items_nonnominal";a:0:{}s:30:"recurring_trial_payment_amount";i:0;s:35:"base_recurring_trial_payment_amount";i:0;s:23:"nominal_subtotal_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_nominal_subtotal_amount";i:0;s:9:"total_qty";i:0;s:19:"base_virtual_amount";i:0;s:14:"virtual_amount";i:0;s:22:"base_subtotal_incl_tax";i:0;s:15:"rounding_deltas";a:0:{}s:23:"nominal_discount_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_nominal_discount_amount";i:0;s:16:"cart_fixed_rules";a:0:{}s:16:"applied_rule_ids";s:0:"";s:19:"nominal_weee_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_nominal_weee_amount";i:0;s:19:"applied_taxes_reset";b:1;s:18:"nominal_tax_amount";i:0;s:23:"base_nominal_tax_amount";i:0;s:31:"base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:18:"free_method_weight";i:0;s:8:"item_qty";i:1;s:11:"region_code";s:2:"CA";s:11:"msrp_amount";i:0;s:16:"base_msrp_amount";i:0;s:19:"freeshipping_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_freeshipping_amount";i:0;s:11:"weee_amount";i:0;s:16:"base_weee_amount";i:0;s:19:"tax_shipping_amount";i:0;s:24:"base_tax_shipping_amount";i:0;s:16:"shipping_taxable";i:0;s:21:"base_shipping_taxable";i:0;s:20:"is_shipping_incl_tax";b:0;}
>                       [profile_vendor_info] => 
>                       [additional_info] =>

Now I want to Pick Product id From That array ,How can i Do So?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time digging through a few `print_r($array)` outputs and it is never much fun. Have you tried anything in particular that hasn't worked? Be sure to let us know what you've tried and what you've come up with.

I think I may be able to help you though.

I'm pretty sure that this will get you what you want:

```
$profiles[order_item_info][product_id]
```

I had to try this out using the terminal and I had to put the names in quotes like the following or I got a "undefined constant" error for my test values so if that throws an error like that, then try this:

```
$profiles['order_item_info']['product_id']
```

I've been away from PHP for a while but I'm pretty sure you can get what you need by digging into this multi-dimensional array.